# Exclude smililar string while using sed

Tags: linux

I have a some scripts into a directory and this directory containing other folders also. Which ever script are residing in my first (parent) directory I want to replace all 'dev' string into prod. but in some of the script I am nullifying the out by using dev/null . I don't want to change this as prod/null.
I am replacing all other 'dev' using below command.

```
grep -rl dev somedir|xargs sed -i 's/dev/prod/g'
```

Please let me know if there is any way to exclude changing dev/null to prod/null

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If each entry in `grep -r1 dev somedir` is separated by a newline, you can use this

```
grep -rl dev somedir | grep -v "dev/null" | xargs sed -i 's/dev/prod/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to replace `/dev/null` to some other string (i.e. `/xxx/null`) before doing `dev` -> `prog` substitution and change it to `/dev/null` later.

```
grep -rl dev somedir|xargs sed -i -e 's!/dev/null!/xxx/null!g' -e 's/dev/prod/g' -e 's!/xxx/null!/dev/null!g'
```